# How to create columns in Excel 2013 using info from another column via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a column (say *MyOriginalColumn*) in Excel 2013 including 300+ rows (*OriginalData* let's say), 3 of them are given as an example below:

```
CN=myCN1,OU=Workstation,OU=123 (Edmonton),OU=Canada,OU=Company1,OU=Domain Computer,DC=xyz,DC=local
CN=myCN2,OU=Local Server,OU=Germany,OU=Company2,DC=xyz,DC=local
CN=myCN3,OU=Disabled,DC=xyz,DC=local
...
```

We know maximum number of OU value a row has is 5. What I want to do is to add OU columns to excel. The output should be look like:

```
MyOriginalcolumn    OU1            OU2               OU3       OU4         OU5
OriginalData        Workstation    123 (Edmonton)    Canada    Company1    Domain Computer
OriginalData        Local Server   Germany           Company2  
OriginalData        Disabled 
...
```

I am doing it by reading the data from excel via C#, but I wonder if there is any way to directly perform it in Excel, via an Excel script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data starting in A2, put this in B2:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID($A2,FIND(",OU=",$A2)+4,FIND(",DC=",$A2)-FIND(",OU=",$A2)-4),",OU=",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

And copy over and down.

[image]